# search_tmp processes slowing whole site and making it inaccessible

Tags: magento-2.1, database, indexing

Magento 2.1.8 installation, left catalog search index running overnight. It appeared to be successful and all products were showing this morning in the store. However shortly after the site has become inaccessible with mySQL processes taking nearly all server resources. The processlist shows queries such as below which all seem to relate to a tmp table for the search index:

```
| 69 | 6106ce650fb5 | localhost | rhr-v2 | Query   | 1876 | Sending data | INSERT INTO `search_tmp_59be3c85852351_60612390` SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id`, MAX(score) AS `re |
```

Any idea what's going on here? Should these processes be running even though the index says it's complete? Can I/could I kill them some how?